# Checking string formats in Java?

Tags: java, string

having problems doing something for a class I'm taking, since I missed a class or two. (I know it's looked down on to 'do someone's homework,' but I'm not looking for that.)

The assignment is as follows:

Write a program to do the following:

- Prompt for input of someone's first, middle, and last name as a single string (using any combination of upper and lowercase letters).
- Check to make sure the name was entered in the correct format (3 names separated by spaces). If the input is not correct, continue to request the input again until the format is correct.
- Capitalize only the first letters of each part of the name, and print out the revised name.
- Print out the initials for that name.
- Print out the name in the format of:  Lastname, Firstname, MI.

The major problem I'm having is the second part of the assignment; I got the first part, and I'm fairly sure I can manage through the rest, after I get the second set up.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestStrings
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    System.out.print("Enter your name as 'First Middle Last': ");
    name = key.nextLine();




}
}
```

From what I've gathered, I need to use the string.split? I'm not sure how to go about this, though, since I need to check to make sure there are three spaces, that aren't just right next to each other or something, such as "John(three spaces)Doe". I assume it's going to be some kind of loop to check through the input for the name.

The catch 22, is that I can't use arrays, or StringTokenizer. I *must* use the substring method.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. :D

Comment: While I'm not a big fan of doing someone else's homework.  Look at the methods for the String class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html  Pay attention to the substring and indexof method.

Comment: Look up regexes, it will be your friend for a long time after school

Comment: @Steven Hickey you should definitely give a try to my code.

Comment: @bluesman I disagree. At this level regexes would fly over his head. He should avoid them like the plague. At least for now.

Answer (score 5):

To point you in the right direction to find the first name(since you cant use arrays):

```
String firstName = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" "));
```

This will get you a substring from the start to the first space.  If you research the indexOf and substring methods you should be able to go from there.

Comment: +1 for reading the OP's question and not doing his assignment for him

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring and the indexOf functions of String class to get what you need.

[String#indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29): Get's the position of a String inside a String.

[String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29): Get's a substring contained in a String.

```
String s = "Luiggi Mendoza J.";
String x;
while(s.indexOf(" ") > 0) {
    x = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "));
    System.out.println(x);
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1);
}
x = s;
System.out.println(x);
```

The program output will be:

```
Luiggi
Mendoza
J.
```

Comment: OP said he cannot use arrays and needs to use the substring method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the matches method if you know how to use regex. If not think about indexOf and substring methods.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop to continuously check whether user entered a string that consists of 3 parts which are seperated via a single space character `' '`, then use `split()` function to verify 3 parts of string. By using `substring()` as demonstrated here you can get names seperately:

```
public static void main ( String [] args )
{
    String name = "";
    boolean ok = false;
    Scanner key = new Scanner( System.in );

    while ( !ok )
    {
        System.out.print( "Enter your name as 'First Middle Last': " );
        name = key.nextLine();
        try
        {
            if ( name.split( " " ).length == 3 )
                ok = true;
        }
        catch ( Exception e ){ }
    }

    if ( ok )
    {
       String firstName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
       String middleName = name.substring(firstName.length()+1, 
                                       name.lastIndexOf(" "));
       String surname = name.substring(middleName.length()+firstName.length()+2,
                                     name.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read the full question OP says he cannot use arrays and has to use substring.

Answer (score 0):

This works using Pattern/Matcher and regexs. Also guards against strings of length 1 when adjusting case.

```
private static String properCase(String str) {
    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
            + (str.length() >= 1 ? str.substring(1).toLowerCase() : "");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean found = false;
    do {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name as 'First Middle Last': ");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\w+?)\\s(\\w+?)\\s(\\w+)+\\s*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(scanner.nextLine());
        found = m.find();
        if (found) {
            String first = m.group(1);
            String middle = m.group(2);
            String last = m.group(3);

            String revised = properCase(first) + " " + properCase(middle)
                    + " " + properCase(last);

            System.out.println(revised);
            System.out
                    .printf("%s %s %s.\n", properCase(last),
                            properCase(first), middle.substring(0, 1)
                                    .toUpperCase());
        }
    } while (!found);
}
```